# Class has similair name as function inside

Tags: php

I've got told this is bad practice and makes my code look "NOOB" aka naming class similarly than function / method inside.

Could I get some additional opinions / input about what's wrong about this, because I'm seriously confused.

Class:

```
class MoonSoon_Init {
    private $input = array();
    private $config = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        return;
    }

    function init()
    {
         // plenty of code here
    }
```

}

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but I don't see 2 similar names.

Comment: @Mr.Smith Neither do I, but I've got flammed because of it. LOL.

Comment: I guess they were refering to your class having `Init` in its name and it has a method called `init()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me a Class name need to tell you what the class manage.

After that a method name need to tell me what it does. The Init is similar (thinking about it) as it's preparing something before using it, so i think picus is right, your "init" method seem similar to the constructor of the class for that purpose.

Having a class name like this one MoonSoon_Init doesn't tell me anything... what is a moonsoon? After that a _init will tell me that this class start something... so there are other classes starting with MoonSoon and ending with other names?

It's a lot foggy to know something faster this way, and i'm talking about middle/big project.

Answer (score 1):

To me, init isn't a bad name for a method per se (see below), but it is a bit weird to have it in a class name. Classes are classes - they can be intialized, constructed, destructed, extended, inherited so on and so forth.

Without knowing what your class is intended to represent, I would say that MoonSoon is fine as a class name - again, my opinion. However, if in the scope of your app, it makes perfect sense to name it the way you have, then do so.

Also, coming from both php and python, I take names init and construct to be logically similar names...

I understand that `__construct()` is the constructor method, but the init method name, `__init__()` to be exact,  is used as a sort of constructor method in python. This may be splitting hairs but it would suggest to me by their name they do the same thing.

What do you intend to do with init that you wouldn't do in __construct?

Comment: +1 i like your way of thinking